# More than one user in the same Controller Spring MVC

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, web, controller

I'm starting to develop for Web and I'm using Spring MVC as my Server Framework. Now I'm wondering about creating variables in Controller class. I had to do it to manage some data in server, but now I'm concerned about the following case: If I have more than one user sending information to the same page, at the same time, would one user interfere on another user variable?

Here's some code example:

```
@Controller
public Class myController {

    int number;


    @RequestMapping("/userInformation")
    public String getInformation(int info) {
       number = info;
    }

    public void doSomethingWithIt() {
       number = number + 1;
   }

}
```

In this case, If I have more than one user sending data to /userInformation at the same time, would Spring MVC create one Controller for each user? This way I wouldn't have problem, I guess. But if not, I have to rethink this implementation, don't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring container will create one instance of your Controller. So all users will share that instance.

If you have data that is private to a user, you have several options:

1. store it in the HTTP session (not recommended if it's a lot of data, as your memory usage might explode)
2. store it in a database and retrieve it upon each request, based on some property identifying the user
3. store it in a memory cache and retrieve it upon each request, based on some property identifying the user

Option 3 is the most simple one of them, you can even implement it as a `Map<User, UserData>` instance variable on your `Controller` if you like. It's not the cleanest, most beautiful or most secure option, just the most simple.

Comment: Thanks! This was the most complete answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are right. Controllers are singletons and must be stateless. Server side state belongs in session or in a data store. You can also use a request scoped object (look at bean scopes in spring).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any instance variables in the Spring Controller that represent state of the controller class. It should not have state since its single instance. Instead you could have references to the injected managed beans.

Comment: I disagree: Spring controllers may have instance variables. If you want to use for example another Spring bean, you want the Spring container to inject that bean for you. That's easiest to achieve if the bean lives as an instance variable in your controller. Only thing is, you should not have instance variables *representing state* on your Controller.

Comment: @mthmulders Thank you, that what I meant...I'll update my answer to be more clear on that!