# Multiple users login in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, heroku, controller

I'm currently working on a java project with Spring and Postgres on Heroku, with most functions finished, but I've run into a major problem:
Whenever several users log in at the same time, their login information and data interferes with one another, due to my naive implementation: a "user" variable in the controller, which is a singleton and is shared across all users.
Why this doesn't work makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I should mention that I have very little experience with web development.

I've searched for possible fixes and it looks like there are multiple solutions, such as using Session Beans, servlets, java's httprequest and other functions, Spring Security, or [instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836136/more-than-one-user-in-the-same-controller-spring-mvc) I've attempted tutorials for these, but probably due to my inexperience, I have yet to get one solution working for my existing code + Spring + Heroku.

My question is this - Which avenue is the best for me to pursue in order to solve my problem? It feels like there is are very simple fixes to this problem but right now I'm not sure what to try next. Simplicity is preferred and security is not a current concern for this project. If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

All my server-side code, with the exception of class files, is currently in the main controller java file, which used to be the "Getting Started With Java" file from Heroku. Many online examples have controllers in multiple files, which I don't know how to integrate into my existing project.

*This is my first question on this site; if there's something I should add to my question, or if this isn't the right place to ask, please let me know. I'm also unsure if any of my code would be helpful for this question.*

Comment: Spring security has support for authentication and authorization. Do you use proper synchronization for your current logged in user variable/information?

Comment: I am not sure your solution should be working anyway. What is your current solution? What do you do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a simple solution, try to reduce the scope of the user variable. Currently, you have a "user" variable in the controller, which is a singleton and is shared across all users, making it local and reducing its scope can solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how can I reduce the scope of the user variable while keeping it in use across all functions in order to identify the current user?

Comment: You want to get the current user in several methods so define a getCurrentUser() and call them in all required methods. In this way, the currentUser variable will be local to those methods.